# Logical OR in HXT without duplicating results

Tags: haskell, xpath, arrows, combinators, monoids

I'm having a little trouble with [HXT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt): I am trying to locate all the nodes in a document that match some criteria, and I'm trying to combine the lenses/XPaths as predicates in an OR-like fashion, using `Control.Arrow.<+>`, as [this guide](http://adit.io/posts/2012-04-14-working_with_HTML_in_haskell.html#get-multiple-values-at-once) suggests. However, when I try to "run" the arrow on my document, I am getting duplicate results. Is there an easy way to remove the duplicates, or to combine the tests in a more meaningful way? Here is my code:

```
run :: App -> IO ()
run a = do
  inputContents <- readFile (input a)
  let doc = readString [withParseHTML yes, withWarnings no] inputContents
  links <- runX . xshow $ doc >>> indentDoc //> cssLinks
  mapM_ putStrLn links

cssLinks = links >>> (rels <+> hrefs <+> types)
  where
    links = hasName "link"
    rels = hasAttrValue "rel" (isInfixOf "stylesheet")
    hrefs = hasAttrValue "href" (endswith ".css")
    types = hasAttrValue "type" (== "text/css")
```

Yet every time I run this (on any web page), I get duplicated results / nodes. I noticed that `<+>` is part of the [ArrowPlus typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t%3aArrowPlus), which mimics a monoid, and [ArrowXML](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.4/docs/Text-XML-HXT-Arrow-XmlArrow.html) is an instance of both [ArrowList](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.4/docs/Control-Arrow-ArrowList.html) and [ArrowTree](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.4/docs/Control-Arrow-ArrowTree.html), which gives me a lot to work with. Would I have to construct [ArrowIf](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.4/docs/Control-Arrow-ArrowIf.html) predicates? Any help with this would be wonderful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get the arrow result as a [XmlTree], then apply List.nub, then get the string rep.

```
import "hxt" Text.XML.HXT.DOM.ShowXml as SX
...

  links <- runX $ doc >>> indentDoc //> cssLinks

  -- first remove duplicates (List.nub) then apply SX.xshow
  putStrLn (SX.xshow . L.nub $ links)
```